# android java code error

Tags: java, android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, local-variables

I am creating a keyboard but there is some error in local variable usage.

```
 private void updateCandidateText(){
        try{

            ExtractedText r= getCurrentInputConnection().getExtractedText(new ExtractedTextRequest(),InputConnection.GET_EXTRACTED_TEXT_MONITOR);
            String strbeforeCursor="";
            String strafterCursor ="";
                strbeforeCursor = getCurrentInputConnection().getTextBeforeCursor(1000000000, 0).toString();
            strafterCursor = getCurrentInputConnection().getTextAfterCursor(1000000000, 0).toString();
            String str = strbeforeCursor + "|"+strafterCursor;
            if(mTamilPreviewView != null)
                mTamilPreviewView.update(str, strbeforeCursor.length());

            mTamilPreviewView.update(r.text.toString() , 0);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("t", "errr", e);
        }    
    }
```

Comment: Can you please tell us what error do you get?

Comment: getting error in local method defenition

Comment: @user2122423: the error comes with a **specific** message. **Reading** this message allows understanding what the error is, instead of guessing. Paste the **complete** and **exact** error message here.

Answer (score 0):

You test if `mTamilPreviewView != null` to call

```
mTamilPreviewView.update(str, strbeforeCursor.length());
```

but even if it's `null`, you'll do

```
mTamilPreviewView.update(r.text.toString() , 0);
```

and you'll get a `NullPointerException`. Is it really what you want to do? Don't you mean

```
if (mTamilPreviewView != null) {
    mTamilPreviewView.update(str, strbeforeCursor.length());
    mTamilPreviewView.update(r.text.toString() , 0);
}
```

Moreover, you initialize `strbeforeCursor` and `strafterCursor` with an empty string, and you give them other values at the next lines. You could simply remove

```
String strbeforeCursor="";
String strafterCursor ="";
```

and do

```
String strbeforeCursor = getCurrentInputConnection().getTextBeforeCursor(1000000000, 0).toString();
String strafterCursor = getCurrentInputConnection().getTextAfterCursor(1000000000, 0).toString();
```